# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen libffmpeg.so: has text relocations

Tags: android, ffmpeg, sdk, android-7.0-nougat

I got an error while using ffmpeg library in android Noughat and above.The error recieved is given below.java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: /data/app/lib/arm/libffmpeg.so: has text relocations.I have used this library for streaming the live videos from a camera device which is connected to my application via wifi. But i was not able to stream video in Noughat and causes crash.I don't want to downgrade my sdk to 22. Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: If this is your app, try to replace **libffmpe.so** witht he latest release version, e.g. from https://github.com/Khang-NT/ffmpeg-binary-android/releases

Comment: @AlexCohn what is I can't use a newer version of the .so fille. is there a way to make it work with the .so file who is producing "has text relocation" error ?

Comment: Why can't you use a newer version? *(sorry it took so long, I was on an offline vacation)*